# How to execute part of "__init__" after __init__ of subclass in python?

Tags: python, oop

I have a problem in Python, which I feel should theoretically be possible to solve, but perhaps not in practice. I have a class which has a lot of different subclasses. Each object of the objects of the subclasses get a name based on some properties that are unique to the subclass. After that name is defined, I want for each of them to execute the same method, but based on that name. So I'd like to put that in the `__init__` of the parent class, but that bit should be executed AFTER execution of the subclass' `__init__`. I suppose I could call some method from the parent class in each of the subclasses' `__init__` at the end, but then I would be copying code and that doesn't feel right to me.
So I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, some_essential_property=1):
        self.some_essential_property = some_essential_property
        # New execute subclass __init__, so that it can make the name
        # Then:
        self.name = self.make_name()
        print(self.name)

    def make_name(self):
        return 'no_special_name'

class Muscle_cell(Cell):
    def __init__(self, strength='huge'):
        super().__init__()
        self.strength = 'huge'

    def make_name(self):
        return 'muscle_with_' + self.strength + '_strength_and_' + str(self.some_essential_property)

M1 = Muscle_cell()
```

This will raise an error because strength isn't known as an attribute yet. That's why I'd like to execute certain lines immediately after the subclass `__init__`.

Comment: Call the super’s `__init__` *after* you’ve set the attribute…!?

Comment: @deceze has already given you the right answer so I won't repeat it. Separate feedback though, you should use UpperCamelCase for your class names: `MuscleCell`, not `Muscle_cell`. :)

Comment: You can call the parent class init after setting the specific name:
`class Muscle_cell(Cell):
    def __init__(self, strength='huge'):
        self.strength = 'huge'
        super().__init__()
`

Comment: @deceze thanks for the suggestion, but note that I want to also use the name attribute in the super's init after it was created by the subclass. In my example it's
    print(self.name)
but in reality it's a much more complicated method that should be executed once the name is known. And I can't execute the complete super's init AFTER setting the name, because then the name can't be constructed because it needs the some_essential_property

Comment: Then you have a logical conundrum you can't really unravel. A depends on B which depends on A. ‍♂️ You *could* simply make it a class attribute, which is available before `__init__`, but whether that works for you or not I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

A superclass should not depend on a subclass, there are other (more OOP ways) to do what you want in Python.

```
import abc

class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, some_essential_property=1):
        self.some_essential_property = some_essential_property

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.make_name()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def make_name(self):
        pass

class Muscle_cell(Cell):
    def __init__(self, strength='huge'):
        super().__init__()
        self.strength = 'huge'

    def make_name(self):
        return 'muscle_with_' + self.strength + '_strength_and_' + str(self.some_essential_property)

M1 = Muscle_cell()
```